how to use Shared SSM Parameter in SSM Document
I have an SSM Document which got one parameter defined as below:
schemaVersion: '2.2'
parameters:
  param1:
    type: String
    default: "{{ ssm:myParameter }}"

How do I use Shared SSM Parameter instead of myParamter? Specifying the parameter name as complete ARN does not work.
schemaVersion: '2.2'
parameters:
  param1:
    type: String
    default: "{{ ssm:arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:123456789012:parameter/myParameter }}"

